# R1C1 cell reference in Google Sheets doesn't work for me

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make a complicated formula work using R1C1 notation. During my troubleshooting I can't even make this work in a cell:

```
=IF(R[0]C[2] = "B", 1, 0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think may be automatic in a script but in a Sheet needs to be forced, eg:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("R[0]C[2]", FALSE) = "B", 1, 0)
```

Comment: The if in that context seems unnecessary even though the INDIRECT function is mandatory

Comment: Specifically the 2nd argument to `INDIRECT` indicates `is_A1_notation`